# How to paste only the first url from a list of urls of images seperated with a comma "," to another cell in Excel

Tags: excel, image, hyperlink, pasting

I am using a .csv excel table for product images for woocommerce store. I want to paste the images into a cell next to the URLs of the images. I am using the function =IMAGE(G2;2) to select the URL and just paste the image from it on the cell next to it.

But some of my cells contain multiple images, for example,/images/image1.jpg, /images/image2.jpg, /images/image3.jpg and I can't do select them and paste them the same way.

How can I select only one of the images and paste it again on the next cell?

Comment: What is the `IMAGE` function?  I don't see it in my version of Excel.  If it is a UDF, perhaps you can easily modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to find the **first** URL on cells with several URLS separated by commas, you can use:

`LEFT(A1;SEARCH(",";A1)-1)`

[image]

The formula works this way:

1. `SEARCH(",";A1)` will find the position of th **first** comma
2. `LEFT(A1;SEARCH(",";A1)-1)` will extract, starting by left, all chars until position of comma minus 1

You can combine this with an IFERROR in case there is no comma (I guess that means there is only 1 single URL in the cell).

In the image above in cell B2 the formula I've used is:

`=IFERROR(LEFT(A2;SEARCH(",";A2)-1);A2)`

If there is no comma, the formula will return the value inside cell. If there is a comma, then it will return all chars starting by left until comma position (minus 1).

Hope you can adapt this to your needs.

**NOTE:** IMAGE function is a Google Sheet function, not Excel.

> **[GS FUNCTION IMAGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093333)**

Notice that, even if they are really similar, Google Sheets and Excel are two different apps, so not all works in both apps. Next time you ask something you want to apply to Google Sheets, use the right tag, please

Comment: Thank you so much! Thank you a lot! You saved me a lot of time. Now the only problem I have is that when I use my iphone to edit some info of the products in the .csv file in the Google Sheets, I do not see the photos, only a blank space, yes the formulas are there, but it is probably a bug in the iPhone Google sheets app?

Comment: That's a totally different question, involving iPhone and Google Sheets. None of them are Excel, so I can't help in anyway in that case. My answer works if you use Excel on PC (actually you tagged the question as Excel).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help again! :)